VBA Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error when trying to assign formula into a specific cell
Sub UpdateFormula_LostRevenuesfromTerminationsinYTD2024()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim startMonth1 As String, endMonth1 As String
Dim startMonth2 As String, endMonth2 As String
Dim startCol1 As Long, endCol1 As Long
Dim startCol2 As Long, endCol2 As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim targetFormula As String
Dim firstCol As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim targetCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula (Do Not Use)") ' Adjust the sheet name as needed

startMonth1 = InputBox("Enter the start month for the first range (e.g., Jan-2023):")
endMonth1 = InputBox("Enter the end month for the first range (e.g., Apr-2023):")
startMonth2 = InputBox("Enter the start month for the second range (e.g., Jan-2024):")
endMonth2 = InputBox("Enter the end month for the second range (e.g., Aug-2024):")

firstCol = ws.Cells(4, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastCol = ws.Cells(4, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

' Find columns with headers matching user input within green cells
For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, firstCol), ws.Cells(4, lastCol)) ' Adjust range to cover all header cells
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142) Then ' Only look in green cells
        If cell.Value = startMonth1 Then startCol1 = cell.Column
        If cell.Value = endMonth1 Then endCol1 = cell.Column
        If cell.Value = startMonth2 Then startCol2 = cell.Column
        If cell.Value = endMonth2 Then endCol2 = cell.Column
    End If
Next cell

If startCol1 = 0 Or endCol1 = 0 Or startCol2 = 0 Or endCol2 = 0 Then
    MsgBox "One or more of the specified months were not found in the green cells."
    Exit Sub
End If

' Convert column numbers to column letters
Dim startColLetter1 As String, endColLetter1 As String
Dim startColLetter2 As String, endColLetter2 As String
startColLetter1 = ColumnLetter(startCol1)
endColLetter1 = ColumnLetter(endCol1)
startColLetter2 = ColumnLetter(startCol2)
endColLetter2 = ColumnLetter(endCol2)

targetFormula = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(CJ5), CJ5=""N/A"", ISNUMBER(CK5), CK5=""N/A"")," & _
                "IF(OR(AND(CJ5<>""N/A"", IFERROR((DATE(YEAR(CJ5), MONTH(CJ5), DAY(CJ5)) > DATE(2023,12,31)), FALSE))," & _
                "AND(CK5<>""N/A"", IFERROR((DATE(YEAR(CK5), MONTH(CK5), DAY(CK5)) > DATE(2023,12,31)), FALSE)))," & _
                "IFERROR(IF(FG5<>"""", """", -SUM(" & startColLetter1 & "5:" & endColLetter1 & "5) + SUM(" & startColLetter2 & "5:" & endColLetter2 & "5)), """"),  ""), """")"

Set targetCell = Nothing
For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
    If cell.Value = "Lost Revenues from Terminations in YTD2024*" Then
        Set targetCell = cell.Offset(1, 0) ' Set target to the cell directly below
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

If targetCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The cell with 'Lost Revenues from Terminations in YTD2024*' was not found."
    Exit Sub
End If

targetCell.Formula = targetFormula

End Sub

VBA Coode. I run into the Run-time error 1004 for " targetCell.Formula = targetFormula " line. The code works in another code when my targetFormula is a shorter formula but doesnt work anymore when i change to this code.
I tried to debug that line, changing the " If cell.Value = "Lost Revenues from Terminations in YTD2024*" Then " line to something else but it does not work.
The code should just paste the dynamic formula targetFormula in the targetCell

This happens when the formula has an error, like referring to a non-existing range/name. Go into debug mode and try to insert the formula manually, does it succeed?

"=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(CJ5), CJ5=""N/A"", ISNUMBER(CK5), CK5=""N/A"")," & _
"IF(OR(AND(CJ5<>""N/A"", IFERROR((DATE(YEAR(CJ5), MONTH(CJ5), DAY(CJ5)) > DATE(2023,12,31)), FALSE))," & _
"AND(CK5<>""N/A"", IFERROR((DATE(YEAR(CK5), MONTH(CK5), DAY(CK5)) > DATE(2023,12,31)), FALSE)))," & _
"IFERROR(IF(FG5<>"""", """", -SUM(" & startColLetter1 & "5:" & endColLetter1 & "5) + SUM(" & startColLetter2 & "5:" & endColLetter2 & "5)), """"), """"), """")"

Right at the end of your formula, you have & "5)), """"), ""), """")" — should that be & "5)), """"), """"), """")" instead?

@Chronocidal Yup the code works now, thank you!
